# Custom Back Button in react navigation v6

Tags: react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

Has React navigation removed headerBackImage in screenOptions to replace back button?
Currently, props headerBackImageSource is there where there is a need of passing Image and headerLeft which replaces the backButton by doesn't behave as back button.

Comment: That's not true. `headerBackImageSource` is a option in `@react-navigation/native-stack` package. `headerBackImage` still exists in`@react-navigation/stack`